# Chrome developer tools won't inspect elements within body tag (mac OSX)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Has anyone else experienced problems with chrome developer tools for OSX not showing any elements / html inside the body tag?

I inspect an element as normal, but instead of seeing the html, I just get the body tag, which cannot be expanded or opened in any way (see attached pic). This makes dev tools useless for css debugging.

I have tried

- deleting and reinstalling Chrome (latest version)
- Resetting Chrome to its defaults
- Restarting my computer
- refreshing and hard refreshing the page

This is all the information I can get, for any element within the body tag :

[image]

Comment: Do you see the content in other browser dev tools? e.g. Firefox?

Comment: Looks like https://crbug.com/829884. If you encounter this frequently you can switch to Chrome Canary.

Comment: I think thats it, @wOxxOm . Thanks for the help! Want to put it in an official answer for others to find?

Comment: I have been getting this bug a lot lately too. It began about 4 days ago and has been pretty persistent.

Comment: I have the same on Linux Chrome 66.

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting this quite often

Comment: Its all becoming clear now... Google have changed their design aesthetic, and it's not trivial to reverse engineer the css to copy it. On GDrive for example, Google have disabled right click AND block dev tools in the way I described above. You can't see their CSS! Sneaky. And not a bug, by design :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue in 2018. Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not a solution but you can do `alt+r` to refresh devtools and it fixes the problem temporarily.

Comment: @Leon It's alt+r to just refresh the dev tools on a mac. You don't need to refresh the whole page.

Comment: For me (on a mac), refreshing the page using cmr+r does not always fix the issue, but doing alt+r seems to fix it consistently 

Comment: This fixes it consistently on Windows as well

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Comment: option + R on mac works excellent. only refreshes the devtool